# Amtrak Roomette luggage security

Tags: usa, security, amtrak

I am looking to taking a trip on the [Southwest Chief](https://www.amtrak.com/southwest-chief-train) Amtrak train and booking a Roomette.  I know that I can sit in my Roomette and watch the world go by, but what I want to know about is how concerned should I be about the security of my stuff when I am not in the Roomette?  EG when I go to the dining car or the observation lounge?

Can the Roomette be secured? Or should I load up with all my valuables (Phone, Tablet, Camera) and take them with me while I am away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, sleeper accommodations on Amtrak cannot be locked from the outside.

Is this something you should be worried about?  I would say you shouldn't be any more worried than on an airplane or other conveyance should you use the lavatory.

Given the lounge, cafe and dining cars is almost always full, I doesn't seem many, including myself, are particularly concerned.  I'll regularly walk up and down a train leaving my bag on the rack, even outside the US.

Short of taking things with you, I would certainly recommend you keep any valuables out of sight.  To be safe, use a lockable case, even a zip tie will do.  If you really want to be extra safe, you can zip tie the case to a fixture (I think the rack has a rail), just not in the way of the Attendant.

Yes, is mostly a deterrent.  If the thief really, really wants your stuff, they will find a way, but at least you're making it easier for them to steal someone else's stuff :O.

There are many videos on YouTube that showcase the roomettes, just make sure you watch one on a Superliner.

Comment: The place to be concerned is at stations, especially those with fairly lengthy stops. An elderly friend of mine had his luggage stolen boarding in Chicago by thieves who simply waited until shortly before departure. They grabbed his valuables and leaped off the train. Taking something with an hour to the next stop (or longer, on the OP's route) is a recipe for police waiting to investigate.

Comment: I disagree that I should be no more worried than being on a plane.  On a plane everyone is in full view of everyone else and you recognize your seat mates and you are not out of your seats for an extended period of time. A Roomette is the opposite of all three of those points.